# Google Cloud Translate API PDF File

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I'm looking to at building a service using the Google Cloud Translate API. I've signed up for the premium edition and just need to work out how to upload a PDF file using NODEjs. I can't find any documentation on how to upload files to the API. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to turn your PDF file into plain text, as the [Google Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/) doesn't handle turning a PDF into the text-only content. After you do that, you can process the text using Node with the [`google-cloud-node`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node) library (you can install it by running `npm install --save google-cloud`).

The following snippet will take some input text, automatically detect the language, and return it translated into Spanish (`es`):

```
var translate = require('google-cloud').translate({
  projectId: 'your Google Cloud project ID here',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
});

var inputText = 'Hello';  // Obviously put your PDF's text content here.
translate.translate(inputText, 'es', function(err, translation) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(translation);  // translation = 'Hola'
  }
});
```